# Accessing Excel columns by names in xlwings

Tags: python, xlwings

In pandas Excel columns can be accessed using names that are assigned in the first row of the sheet. How can this be achieved in xlwings?

Comment: None of the answers solved the issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) as a converter as of xlwings 0.7.0. for an example workbook like this:

```
A  B  C
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9
```

This code will read the table in and allow you to access the data via column headers. The key is the `.options(pd.DataFrame, index=False)` bit. That particular call will return a Pandas DataFrame, with a default index.

More info on xlwings converters [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/converters.html).

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

def calc():    
    # Create a reference to the calling Excel xw.Workbook
    wb = xw.Workbook.caller() 

    table = xw.Range('A1').table.options(pd.DataFrame, index=False).value

    # Access columns as attributes of the Pandas DataFrame
    print table.A
    print table.B

    # Access columns as column labels of the Pandas DataFrame
    print table['A']
    print table['B']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = "test.xlsm"        
    xw.Workbook.set_mock_caller(path)
    calc()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use square brackets to access the columns, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392633/how-to-reference-excel-table-column-names-in-xlwings):

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Workbook.active()
xw.Range('TableName[ColumnName]').value
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'TableName', because all I have is a single Excel sheet with the first row filled with column names.

Comment: It would be nice if you could give an example with xlwings in your answer how to generate the `TableName` part that you used in the first place. `TableName` represents an _Excel table_ (unfortunately the term _Excel table_ seems to be a bit ambiguous, in Microsoft Excel it means that thing which happens when clicking 'Home' tab -> 'Format as table' in Microsoft Excel). Because the problem is, if `TableName` is not defined (see previous comment), the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using only the `xlwings` python library without providing the table name:

```py
import xlwings as xw

#load excelfile
workbook = xw.Book('name_of_excelfile.xlsx')

#get data from sheet "sheet_name" in "name_of_excelfile.xlsx" workbook
sheet = workbook.sheets['Sheet1']

#store first row(header row) data in a list
header_row = sheet.range('1:1').value

#get index of column named "column_name" from header_row list
column_index = header_row.index('column_name') + 1

#get excel column letter from index of column
column_letter = xw.utils.col_name(column_index)

#get the data of column "column_name" as a list
column_data = sheet.range(f'{column_letter}2').expand('down').value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think currently the most efficient way is using:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book("test.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheets[0]

a_col = ws[ws["1:1"].api.Find("column_name").Address].expand("down")
print(a_col.value)
```

although it would be nice if a single function for `a_col` would be implementent in xlwings (corresponding to `df["column_name"]` in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)).
Replace `column_name` with the characters (i.e. the column name) you want to find.