# Read Excel Table headers with xlwings

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlwings

How can I use xlwings to read a "table" in excel, into a pandas DataFrame, where the table "headers" become the DataFrame column names?

Every way I have tried to read the table, the header row is always excluded from the read!

Here is what I've tried, where "b" is my xlwings workbook object:

```
b.sheets['Sheet1'].range('Table1').options(pd.DataFrame)
b.sheets['Sheet1'].range('Table1').options(pd.DataFrame, headers=False)
b.sheets['Sheet1'].range('Table1').options(pd.DataFrame, headers=True)
```

Comment: You can use square bracket access to work with Excel tables, see this answer here and the link there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36396797/918626

Comment: why not just use `pandas.read_excel`?

Comment: can you not save the file as a csv and then pandas.read_csv? I prefer read csv then read excel

Comment: @FelixZumstein looks like that let's me pick specific columns to read, but I want to read all columns, with the headers pulled into the DataFrame

Comment: @MaartenFabré I would be happy to do that, but my table is not the only data on the sheet, so I want to call it by name. I don't think the pandas function can do that, but correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @Tanc27 for the sake of efficiency, I'd like to avoid an extra export step. Thanks!

Comment: wrong, the brackets allow you to access columns and headers/totals rows. Use: Use: `b.sheets['Sheet1'].range('Table1[[#All]]').options(pd.DataFrame)`

Answer (score 2):

Hoping this is not the *best* answer, but I did find I could reference the named range, then `.offset(-1).expand('vertical')`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the api and Excel's ListObject

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.books.active
ws = wb.sheets('MySheet')
tbl = ws.api.ListObjects('MyTable') # or .ListObjects(1)
rng = ws.range(tbl.range.address) # get range from table address

df = rng.options(pd.DataFrame, header=True).value # load range to dataframe
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me add the comment by Felix Zumstein as explicit answer, because in my opinion it is the best solution.

```
df = b.sheets['Sheet1'].range('Table1[[#All]]').options(pd.DataFrame).value
```

Using the square bracket notation expands the selection from the table body to the header row as well. Subsequently the conversion to a pandas DataFrame, can use it as header.

To read more, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36396797/918626).