# Python Xlwings exceution Issue

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

I am using xlwings 0.23.1 to work with MS excel 365.

but when I execute the following code:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.books.active
ws = wb.sheets('MySheet')
tbl = ws.api.ListObjects('MyTable') # or .ListObjects(1)
rng = ws.range(tbl.range.address) # get range from table address

df = rng.options(pd.DataFrame, header=True).value # load range to dataframe
```

the above code stucks at

```
 rng = ws.range(tbl.range.address) # get range from table address
```

and does not exceute.

The code is taken from:
[Read Excel Table headers with xlwings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793540/read-excel-table-headers-with-xlwings)

I am using Spyder IDE

Comment: Note that meanwhile, tables are well supported: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#table

Answer (score 1):

With my local installation xlwings 0.16.0, your code works; but it fails as you described after upgrading to 0.23.0. It seems after a certain version, xlwings strictly separates `xlwings` object and the associated `win32com` object (generally converted by `.api`).

A fix is changing the line from

```
rng = ws.range(tbl.range.address) # get range from table address
```

to (Capitalize `range` and `address`)

```
rng = ws.range(tbl.Range.Address) # get range from table address
```

For a `win32com` object, its api usually capitalizes the first letter, while all lower cases for `xlwings`. The code in third line `ws.api` returns a `win32com` object, then `tbl`, so `.range.address` is affected accordingly.